# Image not being loaded in Android

Tags: java, android-layout, picasso

I am new to android. I cannot load picture in my app. The main code is

```
   package com.example.deepakchethan.imagedisplay;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        ImageView imageView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageContainer);
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/z4x0Bp48ar3Mda8KiPD1vwSY3D8.jpg").into(imageView);
        }
    }`
```

The xml is

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.deepakchethan.imagedisplay.MainActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageContainer"
            tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    </RelativeLayout>`
```

But still the image has not been loaded. What to do now. Please tell. I need to learn.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: image not loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your code. But have you asked for **permission** in the manifest file. It is important if you have not added. Type this code to your minifest.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Let me know, if you still have the problem.